# Knex and PostgreSQL: How to drop an unique index?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have an app using knex for migration. Earlier someone made an unique index on one column using `knex.raw` like this:

```
const createProgrammeTable = knex => knex.raw(`
  CREATE TABLE programme (
    id             serial PRIMARY KEY,
    date           date NOT NULL,
    published      date,
    description    text
  );
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX programme_date_index ON programme(date);
`)
```

When printing out the db using psql I get this info:

```
server=# \d programme;
                              Table "public.programme"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                Default
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id        | integer |           | not null | nextval('programme_id_seq'::regclass)
 date      | date    |           | not null |
 published | boolean |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "programme_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "programme_date_index" UNIQUE, btree (date)
```

**Now I want to remove the unique constraint but I'm not sure how.** I've read that I can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE programme DROP INDEX programme_date_index;
```

But doing that using `knex.raw` gives this error:

```
migration failed with error: ALTER TABLE programme DROP INDEX programme_date_index - syntax error at or near "programme_date_index"
error: ALTER TABLE programme DROP INDEX programme_date_index - syntax error at or near "programme_date_index"
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/my-path/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:555:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/my-path/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:380:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/my-path/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:120:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I've also tried using [dropUnique](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-dropUnique) like this:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable("programme", function(t) {
    t.dropUnique("date", "programme_date_index")
  })
}
```

which gives the following error:

```
migration failed with error: alter table "programme" drop constraint "programme_date_index" - constraint "programme_date_index" of relation "programme" does not exist
```

**Versions**

Knex CLI version: 0.20.15 /
Knex Local version: 0.20.15

```
server=# select version();
                                                     version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Can someone please help me/push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

```
export async function down(db: Knex): Promise<void> {
    db.schema.alterTable('tablename', function (t) {
        t.dropUnique([], 'indexname')
    })
}
```

Incase you're using typescript to remove index.

Comment: This Typescript was helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

using Knex with Posgresql, I've just resolved a similar problem this way:

```
import * as Knex from "knex";

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
    return await knex.schema
        .withSchema('public')
        .table('elements', (table) => {
            table.dropUnique(null, 'elements_name_unique');
        });
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
    return knex.schema.table('elements', (table) => {
        table.unique(['name']);
    });
}
```

Typescript constraint made it weird and I had to cheat a little with parameters.

I use Knex CLI version: 0.21.17 / Knex Local version: 0.21.18

Answer (score 0):

Package

```
"knex": "^0.95.8",
```

This is what I normally do:

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('users', function (table) {
    table.dropUnique('user_id');
  });
};
exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('users', function (table) {
    table.unique('user_id');
  });
};
```

But we ran into this interesting issue where we altered the column name before and renamed the column. For some reason the database still had a constraint with old column name as unique. So we had to remove the old constraint first. Something to keep in mind!